# how to detect two nodes collision point in Sprite kit and objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, nodes

I have two SKSpriteNode's, i know how to detect if they are in same place, but I cant figure out how to detect in which place of node they have collision. I particular want to know one of nodes collision place, because I want to add different `applyImpulse` on nodes height ends, so another node will change direction.

Comment: can't you find the node positon in the collision detected method ? You can always get the node postion in the didBeginContact method. Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: well, with that I detect collision of full node, but I want to detect in which place of  node collision was happen. Can you understand? Because my English isn't my first language.

Comment: you can always get the cgpoint of the node at collision, but I am not sure if you can get the exact collision point of two nodes.

Comment: alternative what I found was to create two nodes and put beside each other, but I still want to know if my question is possible

Comment: @TejaNandamuri one of nodes is moving, so I think its incorrect to use cgpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didBeginContact` is passed an `SKPhysicsContact` when 2 bodies collide. SKPhysocsContact has a property `contactPoint` which is a `CGPoint` and is the contact point between the two physics bodies, in scene coordinates. From this and the positions of your 2 bodies when they collide, you could work out where exactly on the bodies the collision took place.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the contact point like:

```
CGPoint collidedPoint = contact.contactPoint;
```

You can get the x & y points like below:

```
NSLog(@"collidedPoint x= %f | %f",collidedPoint.x,collidedPoint.y); 
// Prints like: collidedPoint x= 424.855835 | 46.139378
```

Keep Coding........ :)